Copying ObjectBox databases from old to new, doesn't seem to keep ToMany relationships
I am trying to reduce the file size of my data.mdb file, as it's getting out of hand, and so I'm deleting/archiving a lot of data. However, as I'm lead to believe, this doesn't actually reduce the file size, it sort of keeps the space empty for future reuse or something like that.
So, I'm attempting to do what I've read suggested, which is to create a new db, and copy all the data into it. This seems to work fine, and the data.mdb is definitely smaller.
However, none of the ToMany information seems to get copied, at least the way I'm doing it. The ToOne stuff works fine, so maybe it's something to do with the way I have my Entities set up, or maybe ToMany just doesn't work that way?
This is how I'm copying the data.
Class[] classes = {ClassA.class, ClassB.class, ClassC.class};

for (Class aClass : classes) {
    newMainDB.getBox(aClass).put(oldMainDB.getBox(aClass).getAll());
}

I've tried arranging the order of the classes so that the ToMany data is already in the db, but it still doesn't work.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

My suspicion is that this won't work because the IDs of the objects in the relation are different in the new database? Though it's odd that it works for ToOne then.

My thoughts exactly. After it didn't work, I thought, I guess that makes sense, but then the ToOne working confused me. Thanks for your help @Uwe-ObjectBox
